# RadioButton value in android

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiobutton

Here's the scenario:
[image]

I made some questions in one activity and every answer has a point(0 to 3). For example if the user select the first one, he gets 0 point, if he select the secound one he will get 1 point etc(2 point for the third one and 3 point for the forth).

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.first_radiobutton) {
                totalPoint = totalPoint + 0;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.secound_radiobutton) {
                totalPoint = totalPoint + 1;
            }else if (checkedId == R.id.third_radiobutton) {
                totalPoint = totalPoint + 2;
            }else if (checkedId == R.id.forth_radiobutton) {
                totalPoint = totalPoint + 3;
            }
        }
    });
```

I made `totalPoint` as global variable and initialize it as `public static int totalPoint = 0;` . The problem  is that if the user has changed his mind and select another answer for the current question, the `totalPoint` variable will add the point to itself. For example imagine that if the user click on the third `radioButton` , the `totalPoint` variable will be 2, so if the user has changed his mind and select the forth `radioButton`, the `totalPoint` must be 3 but instead it will be 5(2+3). How can I avoid this?

Comment: always there will be 4 buttons or it will dynamic?

Comment: Try to save last selected position or radiogroupid  (default = -1) of radiogroup and when you select new one try to remove the Points related to last selected position...

Comment: @Pavan each question has 4 available answer.

Comment: why don't you add the values in `Next` button click?

Comment: you have to store the points in an array(List). The index is the number of the question. If the user like to change his answer on the previews question you have to change the point in the array(List) at the index = the number of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Use an array `answers[]` to store the answer `points` for specific `question`.

**2.** In `onCheckedChanged()`, check selected `RadioButton` and store allocated `points` under specific `question` by using the value of `currentQuestion`.

**3.** Calculate `total` points by `adding` the `values` of `answers` array.

**Here is the working code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;

    int totalPoint = 0;
    int answers[] = new int[10]; // Required for 10 questions (0 to 9)
    int currentQuestion = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                // Store points of specific question using position currentQuestion
                if (checkedId == R.id.first_radiobutton) {
                    answers[currentQuestion] = 0;
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.second_radiobutton) {
                    answers[currentQuestion] = 1;
                }else if (checkedId == R.id.third_radiobutton) {
                    answers[currentQuestion] = 2;
                }else if (checkedId == R.id.forth_radiobutton) {
                    answers[currentQuestion] = 3;
                }

                // Total
                totalPoint = getTotalPoint();
            }
        });
    }

    public int getTotalPoint() {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
            sum += answers[i];

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. How can I save status of the RadioButtons in this situation in sharedpreference. is it possible? because there are only 4 radionbuttons in one activity at a time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331848/how-to-save-radiobutton-status-with-sharedprefrence

Comment: YES you can store this value in shared preferences. OK I will try my best to answer your question

Comment: If my answer seems useful, hope you will vote it up. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

declare one int array at class

```
 int arrValues[]={0,0,0,0}; ///size can be differ as per question length you can create dynamic too as per your requirement
```

and maintain on question counter or position
`int iPosition=0;` ///handle it on on previous and next

then in setOnCheckedChangeListener add following code

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.first_radiobutton) {
               arrValues[iPosition] = 0;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.secound_radiobutton) {
                arrValues[iPosition] =  1;
            }else if (checkedId == R.id.third_radiobutton) {
               arrValues[iPosition]=  2;
            }else if (checkedId == R.id.forth_radiobutton) {
              arrValues[iPosition] =  3;
            }
        }
    });
```

and final step get addition of all value from array